# Get only command as output in ps aux AIX

Tags: linux, unix, aix, ps

With the below command:

```
# ps aux 
USER   PID %CPU %MEM   SZ  RSS    TTY STAT    STIME  TIME COMMAND
root 17760468 0.0 0.0 1180 1220 - A 18:15:00 0:00 iostat -Dsal 6
root 16777310 0.0 0.0 3172 408 - A 18:15:00 0:00 /usr/bin/perl
```

here i don't want `iostst -Dsal 6` under COMMAND, instead it should show only `iostat`. I mean only command is needed not with its all options and parameters.

Reason for this query:
I am trying to use this below command on my AIX box -

```
ps aux | tr -s " " | head -1 | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$11}' ; ps aux | sort -rn +2 | tr -s " " | head -10 | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$NF}'
```

Since i have used NF in awk command, it will display only the last column of the line. In my case it will display "`6`" instead of `iostst -Dsal 6` under COMMAND field.

Please help me here..!

Comment: Would something like `ps -o user,pid,pcpu,pmem,comm | sort -rn +2 | head -10` work?

Comment: I have to use `aux` option for ps command..!
But if i execute like below it errors out :
FYI...
`ps aux -o user,pid,pcpu,pmem,comm | sort -rn +2 | head -10`



Output is ERROR
`Usage: ps [-AMNZaedfklm] [-n namelist] [-F Format] [-o specifier[=header],...]
                [-p proclist][-G|-g grouplist] [-t termlist] [-U|-u userlist] [-c classlist] [ -T pid] [ -L pidlist ]
                [-@ [wparname] ]
Usage: ps [aceglnsuvwxX] [t tty] [processnumber]`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the aux part. Does `ps -e -o user,pid,pcpu,pmem,comm` show you all the processes?

Comment: Ya it works..! i did the same. 
My doubt is why `aux` option is not working..!

Comment: There are two popular versions of ps, and they have conflicting option names. One uses hyphens in front of options, the other doesn't. AIX has a single ps command that offers the functionality of both versions, but you can only use one version at a time. So you can't combine `aux` with `-o`. But `-e` ought to do the same thing as `ax`.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info..!